# python reading header from word docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx, python-watchdog

I am trying to read a header from a word document using python-docx and watchdog.
What I am doing is, whenever a new file is created or modified the script reads the file and get the contents in the header, but I am getting an

```
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'Test6.docx'
```

error and I tried everything including opening it as a stream but nothing has worked, and yes the document is populated.
For reference, this is my code.

```
**main.py**
    import time
    from watchdog.observers import Observer
    from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
    import watchdog.observers
    import watchdog.events
    import os
    import re
    import xml.dom.minidom
    import zipfile
    from docx import Document


    class Watcher:
        DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/path/to/my/directory"

        def __init__(self):
            self.observer = Observer()

        def run(self):
            event_handler = Handler()
            self.observer.schedule(event_handler,path='C:/Users/abdsak11/OneDrive - Lärande', recursive=True)
            self.observer.start()
            try:
                while True:
                    time.sleep(5)
            except:
                self.observer.stop()
                print ("Error")

            self.observer.join()


    class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

        @staticmethod
        def on_any_event(event):
            if event.is_directory:
                return None

            elif event.event_type == 'created':
                # Take any action here when a file is first created.
                path = event.src_path
                extenstion = '.docx'
                base = os.path.basename(path)

                if extenstion in path:
                    print ("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
                    time.sleep(10)
                    print(base)
                    doc = Document(base)
                    print(doc)
                    section = doc.sections[0]
                    header = section.header
                    print (header)



            elif event.event_type == 'modified':
                # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
                path = event.src_path
                extenstion = '.docx'
                base = os.path.basename(path)
                if extenstion in base:
                    print ("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)
                    time.sleep(10)
                    print(base)
                    doc = Document(base)
                    print(doc)
                    section = doc.sections[0]
                    header = section.header
                    print (header)



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        w = Watcher()
        w.run()
```

Edit:
Tried to change the extension from doc to docx and that worked but is there anyway to open docx because thats what i am finding.

another thing. When opening the ".doc" file and trying to read the header all i am getting is

```
<docx.document.Document object at 0x03195488>
<docx.section._Header object at 0x0319C088>
```

and what i am trying to do is to extract the text from the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print the object itself, however you should access its property:

```
...
doc = Document(base)
section = doc.sections[0]
header = section.header
print(header.paragraphs[0].text)
```

according to https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html)

**UPDATE**

As I played with **python-docx** package, it turned out that PackageNotFoundError is very generic as it can occur simply because file is not   accessible by some reason - not exist, not found or due to permissions, as well as if file is empty or corrupted. For example, in case of watchdog, it may very well happen that after triggering "created" event and before creating **Document** file can be renamed, deleted, etc. And for some reason you make this situation more probable by waiting 10 seconds before creating **Document**? So, try checking if file exists before:

```
if not os.path.exists(base):
    raise OSError('{}: file does not exist!'.format(base))
doc = Document(base)
```

**UPDATE2**

Note also, that this may happen when opening program creates some lock file based on file name, e.g. running your code on linux and opening the file with libreoffice causes

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at '.~lock.xxx.docx#'
```

because this file is not docx file! So you should update your filtering condition with

```
if path.endswith(extenstion):
...
```

Comment: thanks but do you have a solution for the other problem ?

Comment: @abodsakka you mean PackageNotFoundError? I wonder, how these files are created, are they doc or docx? Because python-docx works only with docx.

Comment: 1. When i use a .doc as a document it works but when i use a .docx as a document it would throw at me a package not found error.                      2. The documents are created in Microsoft word 2019.                           3. Yah the base thing was an mistake, i was trying around to see if that maybe would work for some reason but it didnt and it was then that i gave up and posted the question XD

Comment: @abodsakka have you tried to open through file object? I haven't clearly understood if renaming just helps or saving documents in Microsoft Word under different formats? Can you compare then two documents with some differ (they should be xml inside)? Maybe newest format of MW is not supported yet or you need to update your python-docx to the latest version...

Comment: Yes i have tried to open through a file system, it was infact the first thing i tried. And yes just renaming the file from ".docx" extenstion to ".doc" made it work

Comment: @abodsakka just curious, what if you rename but leave the same extension? I guess the problem might be with the access to the file you are trying to open. So, try to copy it to another folder before opening, or rename adding _ underscore in the beginning... BTW, how do you rename it?

Comment: @abodsakka no, the updates in answer, basically to check if file exists before opening to rule out that simple thing

Comment: Yah i just did that but it is finding the file i used : 
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                print ("file exist \n\n\n")
and its printing "file exist" so thats not the problem

Comment: @abodsakka then permissions, next step is to check if file is readable, can wrap it with:  try:
  with open(path) as fp:
           doc = Document(path)
except IOError:
    print("could not read", path)

Comment: i tried what you said but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: i uploaded the project to github with the error if you would like to take a look on it: https://github.com/abodsakah/word-automation

Comment: @abodsakka ok, in what directory are you running this script?

Comment: I am runing the script from an another directory, my github directory and trying to access the file from my onedrive directory

Comment: @abodsakka if you are running from another directory - you can't use Document(base) - how would it find in which directory file is located?

Comment: No i know i have the base just to get the name because i am going to use later to give a toast on windows and i am using the path instead to find the file and the directory of the file

Comment: @abodsakka sorry, but it looks that you are mixing things/problems and it's difficult to understand for me why, your problem with PackageNotFoundError is due to the line #43 Document(base), no matter what does you need "base" for, the Document constructor should have the full path to the document, so I can't see why you can't have Document(path) as on the line #54

Comment: @abodsakka I don't believe it's the same as https://github.com/abodsakah/word-automation/blob/master/error.txt

Comment: @abodsakka anyway. you stil have to use Document(path), if you have the same or another error - it just means that there is something else to fix. Now I also noticed that you have mixed path separators linux vs windows - strange, The path to watch C:/Users/abdsak11/OneDrive - Lärande should  be "C:\Users\abdsak11\OneDrive - Lärande" - since WIndows uses backslash